# Why is a list containing an empty string truthy?

Tags: python-3.x

I have caught something in my work returning a list containing an empty string. I've created an example for simplicity:

```
big_ol_trickster = [""]
if big_ol_trickster:
    foo()
else:
    print("You can't trick me!")
```

And this conditional would be satisfied every time. So I've got a question for the python wizards out there: Why is `[] == False` and `"" == False` but `[""] == True`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Empty** lists are `Falsey`. `[""]` is not empty. It contains a single element (which happens to be `Falsey` as well). The `Falsey`-ness is not evaluated recursively.

To know why is that, look at the implementation of the [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) dunder method for the `list` class. This the method that is called to evaluate truth-value in python. And, yes, you can override it.

`[False, False]` -> this is also `Truthy`, it can be counter-intuitive. That's why when you try to use sequences in if conditions you sometimes get `"truth-value of sequences can be ambiguous, use any() or all() instead"`

Comment: Thanks @DroidX86. Would you happen to know the reason why `Falsey`-ness is not evaluated recursively?

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say performance. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: Recursive falseyness would be unintuitive and difficult to reason about. Empty lists would be False, but so would an infinite variety of other lists. What would you use the concept for? Also, performance and possibilities for infinite recursion: what if you have a list containing a dict which in turn references the original list?

Comment: @JussiNurminen you've made some good points. I wasn't trying to use this concept. Rather, I was asking out of general curiosity. However I have a solution to your question regarding infinite recursion which is very similar to the solution for avoiding accidentally writing infinitely recursive functions: Just don't do it.